# Upload file from SonarQube dashboard

Tags: sonarqube, erb, sonarqube-web

I am new to SonarQube and developing my own plugin. I am parsing an XML file in my plugin and I have hard coded it but now I want to upload that file from SonarQube dashboard. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is this XML file a file under analysis or some sort of configuration for your plugin?

Comment: It is required for configuration of my plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this file is used for user-supplied configuration use properties instead.

You can take a look at the [Java plugin](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/sonar-java-plugin/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/java/JavaPlugin.java) for plugin-level configuration, and at [Widget Lab](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-widget-lab/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/sonar/plugins/widgetlab/ClockWidget.java) for widget-level config.